# C contiguous data arrays

Tags: arrays, c, fonts, contiguous

Say I have 2 arrays of data:

```
const uint8_t data1[] = {0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07};
const uint8_t data2[] = {0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f};
```

I would like to be able to read these individually, but also as one contiguous block of data.

eg: I could access data1[8] in the same way as data[0].

Reason: I have various const data definitions in some individual .c files that I'd rather not touch (font bitmaps) but I'd like to append some extra data to them (extra special characters). So I'd like to

```
#include <original font file>
const uint8_t extrafonts[] = {<more font bitmaps>};
```

Can this be done?

Comment: It's not clear how the second code snippet relates to the first. Suggest making the second snippet refer to the same variables as the first to make it clearer. That is, give a concrete example instead of an abstract one.

Comment: Imagine the original font file just contains const uint8_t fonts[] = {<some font bitmaps>};

Comment: Yes, but how does `fonts` related to `extrafonts`. It's really not clear what you are asking. But if you really have two seperate arrays then there is no way in general to treat them as a single contiguous array. This really sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). But you are not explaining what you are actually trying to do clearly enough for any suggestion to be provided to you.

Comment: I assume you mean "`data1[8]` in the same way as `data2[0]`"? No, `data1[8]` is out of bounds and invokes undefined behavior. You can do `data[] = {0x0, 0x1 ... 0xf}` and then have `uint8_t* data1 = &(data[0]); uint8_t* data2 = &(data[8]);`, then `data1[8] == data2[0]`, but you cannot assume that 2 separate arrays will be in the same contiguous memory back to back. I too am confused with the rest of your question.

Comment: > "but you cannot assume that 2 separate arrays will be in the same contiguous memory back to back." OK. Is there any way that this can be forced, so that it's guaranteed they're back-to-back? That's what I'm after. That way if I access the first array with an out of bounds index I know I'm actually accessing the second array.

Comment: typedef one array[8], then define another array[2] of that.  That should guarantee contiguous memory, no?   Myself, I would just use a struct like in Jonathan answer - not failed me yet, though I do take care to use alignable types like uint8_t[8] so as to not provoke the compiler into leaving gaps:)

Answer (score 2):

The only way to guarantee contiguous allocation in C is to use arrays of arrays. In this case it would seem that a `const uint8_t [2][8]` would solve all your problems, so use that if possible.

Otherwise, more advanced solutions could use structs and unions. These guarantee an order of allocation but come with the disadvantage that the compiler can insert padding anywhere. In this specific case it wouldn't be a problem on any real-world computer, since chunks of 8 bytes are aligned. If you have a standard C compiler, you can do this:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef union
{
  struct
  {
    uint8_t data1 [8];
    uint8_t data2 [8];
  };
  uint8_t data [16];
} data_t;

int main (void)
{
  const data_t data = 
  {
    .data1 = {0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07},
    .data2 = {0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f},
  };
  
  for(size_t i=0; i<16; i++)
  {
    printf("%.2"PRIx8" ", data.data[i]);
  }
}
```

Now you can access the arrays individually through `data.data1`/`data.data2` or as one, with `data.data`.

In cases where you worry about struct padding, you'll have to add some non-standard `#pragma pack(1)` or similar compiler-specific instruction.

Comment: "_it would seem that a `const uint8_t [2][8]` would solve all your problems..._" -- isn't this strictly UB, as described in [Annex J.2](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2): "_An array subscript is out of range, even if an object is apparently accessible with the given subscript (as in the lvalue expression a[1][7] given the declaration int a[4][5])_"?

Comment: @adabsurdum Depends on how you access it. I didn't say you were allowed to access each array in the array-of-arrays out of bounds. And why would you... just iterate over each index. `for(size_t i=0; i<2; i++) for(size_t j=0; j<8; j++) a[i][j] = whatever;`

Comment: I misunderstood your suggestion; OP seems to want to access two arrays as if they are one, and I thought that you were suggesting that this 1d access could be applied to a 2d array; now I see what you meant: just use a 2d array as they were meant to be used.

Answer (score 1):

There is another alternative that might be applicable to your use case: Use external preprocessing.

Use your favorite scripting language with some regular expression magic to read original font source file, and append extra font data at the end of array. Then save it to new file and use that in compilation instead.

This might seem a lot of work at first, but c files which are generated by tools (which I assume is the case with your font bitmaps) tend to have predictable format that is not too hard to parse.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use:

```
struct ArrayPair
{
    uint8_t data1[8];
    uint8_t data2[8];
};

const struct ArrayPair data =
{ 
    { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07 },
    { 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f }
};
```

Now you can probably get away with using:

```
data.data1[8]
```

It isn't very elegant.  Your requirement is not sensible.

Comment: Maybe with a 'packed' pragma though, with types lime 'uint8_t data1[8];', I doubt any further compiler-hobbling is required:)

Comment: This is strictly speaking undefined behavior. The compiler might assume that either array is never accessed out of bounds and generate code accordingly. See [this](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277215) where I wrote an answer demonstrating how a compiler can go bananas when accessing out of bounds.

Comment: In a highly theoretical scenario there could also be padding between the arrays on some super-exotic system. That's not really something we need to consider, but the array out of bounds code generation bug is a real thing.

Answer (score 0):

You said that these are 2 global arrays on different source files. So I am ignoring any options where you can group these with unions or structures.

Now the bad news: There is absolutely no guarantee that 2 global variables will end up next to each other in memory with standard C rules.

You can do this, but you need to use compiler specific extensions instead. You need to:

- Use manual memory placement to place variables next to each other.
- Disable any optimizations or other compiler features that might break your code because you are accessing array out of bounds.

Note that I am assuming that you are in system where resources are limited, for example, some embedded system. If that is not the case, then simply create third array, and merge 2 arrays at program startup.